# Log4J2 set params in appender

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Using log4j2 how can I configure my PatternLayout to print more than just the message but the Map param that I sending in

```
       void info(String message, Object... params);
```

Here my code

```
         Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(REMOTE_HOST, request.remoteAddress()
                                       .toString());
        params.put(URI, request.uri());
        params.put(METHOD, request.method()
                                  .toString());
        params.put(REMOTE_HOST, request.remoteAddress()
                                       .toString());
        params.put(REFERER, request.headers()
                                   .get(HttpHeaders.REFERER));
        params.put(USER_AGENT, request.headers()
                                      .get(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT));
        params.put(STATUS_CODE, Integer.toString(response.getStatusCode()));
        params.put(RESPONSE_CONTENT_LENGTH, response.headers()
                                                    .get(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH));
        params.put(TIME, getTime(start, getNano));
        log.info(request.absoluteURI(), params);
```

And my Appender

```
    <File name="requestLog" fileName="request.log" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n  "/>
    </File>
```

For now only is printing

```
    2016-08-04 15:57:32.288 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  requestLog - http://localhost:8080/v4/quote
```

Comment: Check out the `log4j2` `Messages` object library.  It contains methods that are designed to digest `Map` objects.

Comment: That´s good, and I can use MessageMap for params, but in the documentation https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/messages.html does not explain how to configure your appender in the log4j2.xml and still does not show any parameter. Any idea?

Comment: No, I frankly have only used Log4j2 to log formatted strings, not Map objects.  I was just aware of the methods existing.  Sorry paul.

Comment: no worries thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a format string:

```
log.info("URI: {}, parameters: {}", request.absoluteURI(), params);
```

In your code, the URI is treated as a format string, but since it has no placeholders, it just prints the URI and ignores the parameters.